# Put an extra cell in a table without an attached column

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to add an extra table cell to a table, that isn't attached to a column.  It just sticks out of the table like a 'bump'  I not entirely sure what kind of styling I would need to achieve this.

**What I would like it to look like this:**

[image: table]

**My code:**

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td style="border-style:none">extra</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would think I need to add an empty `<th>` and remove the border from it and then add it to the last cells in the table?

Comment: Use the colspan property!!!

Comment: @ErnestoGonzalezMartin But I don't want the table header to 'cover' the extra cell.  I want it to 'stick out' indepedently

Comment: Maybe its time to abandon tables altogether and go with divs instead? With divs this is a non-issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do like below:

```css
    table{
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
     }
    table tr td:last-child{
      border: none;
    }
    table td, table th{
      border: 1px #666 solid;
    }
    table tr:last-child td:last-child{
      border:  1px #666 solid;
    }
```

```html
  
  <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>extra</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you!  This definitely helped.  I might up rethinking how I am doing this though.  Perhaps redoing code using divs like @imvain2 suggested, might be the ultimately better option.

Comment: there is also the `:emty` pseudo class which was the way to hide empty cells ;)

Answer (score 0):

With javascript, you can do it like *(of course you would change `nth-child(3)` to your target column)*:

```js
var row = document.createElement('td')
row.innerHTML = 'teste'
document.querySelector('table tr:nth-child(3)').append(row)
```

```html
<table id="test">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td style="border-style:none">extra</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```